# Get & Set Request Header Key values using Reflection C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, httprequest, system.reflection

Using Reflection, I am trying to fetch the request headers of .NET Core web app. I could access the Scheme, Method, etc from the Request object as in the below code,

```
reqObj.GetType().GetProperty("Scheme").GetValue(reqObj, null).ToString();
```

I couldnt get the headers of the request object(The class linked [HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-2.2) ). I am using the lines below that tries to get the Headers and I need to get the keyvalue pairs in it.

```
Object headerObj = reqObj.GetType().GetProperty("Headers").GetValue(reqObj,null);

var items = headerObj.GetType().GetProperty("Keys", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(headerObj,null);
```

Here I should get the ICollection of strings. But on that line the process is getting crashed. Even i tried to typecast the `headerObj` to `ICollection<KeyValuePair<String,StringValues>>` . But trying those things too gives me a crash.

Here I need to print the header keys and values using Reflection.. Also i m trying to add a key value pair in the header using Reflection. How can i achieve these?

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to use Reflection to achieve the above? `HttpRequest` object has a `Headers` property, you can use that to achieve the same

Comment: @ShahzadHassan - yes .. I am working on a instrumentation Profiler..  I am going to access it from a external assembly that does not refer to Microsoft.aspnetcore.http modules.. Hence i need to access by reflection only

Comment: But still, why not just reference the assembly? If your code depends on the classes to exist and to have certain properties - which means that it wouldn't work without the assembly - then why not reference it? If for some reason I had to work with that constraint I would probably end up just creating my own wrapper that looked like an `HttpRequest` but internally did reflection, just so that the rest of my code would be strongly typed. But I wouldn't do that - I'd just reference the assembly that contains the classes I'm working with.

Comment: my external assembly has to be in GAC and so it has to be compiled in .NET Framework v3.5(the reason i cannot refer to that CORE modules). The static function in that assembly will just rececive a httpcontext object. With the httpcontext object i need to get the details of the request by using reflection.